# std::map replace existing elements by transform

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a code:

```
std::vector<int> vector = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
using my_type = std::pair<int, int>;
std::map<int, boost::optional<my_type>> map;
for (const auto &i : vector) {
    map[i] = boost::none;
}
const my_type val = {1, 5};
std::transform(vector.cbegin(),
               vector.cend(),
               std::inserter(map, map.end()),
               [&val](const int &i) {
                   return std::make_pair(i, boost::optional<my_type>(val));
});
```

Everything works fine but `std::transform` does not change the map by replacing values with the existing key, so I have this:

```
{ 
    {1, boost::none},
    {3, boost::none},
    {5, boost::none},
    {7, boost::none},
    {9, boost::none},
}
```

Is it possible to make it work as following simple range-based for?

```
for (const auto &i : vector) {
    map[i] = boost::optional<my_type>(val));
}
```

P.S. I know how the `std::inserter` works and `std::map::insert` too, just curious how can I change the transform in order to change values.

Comment: `map[i] = boost::optional<my_type>(val));` should work but then why use `map[i] = boost::none;` in the first `for` loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not with `inserter`, since `insert` inserts elements only and only if there is no element in `map`.
There will be [insert_or_assign](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert_or_assign) in C++17.

```
template<typename Map>
struct map_insert_iterator : public std::iterator<std::output_iterator_tag, void, void, void, void>
{
public:
   map_insert_iterator(Map& m) : map(m)
   {
   }
   map_insert_iterator<Map>& operator = (const typename Map::value_type& value)
   {
      map.insert_or_assign(value.first, value.second);
      return *this;
   }
   map_insert_iterator<Map>& operator * () { return *this; }
   map_insert_iterator<Map>& operator ++ () { return *this; }
   map_insert_iterator<Map>& operator ++ (int) { return *this; }
private:
   Map& map;
};

template<typename Map>
map_insert_iterator<Map> map_inserter(Map& m)
{
   return map_insert_iterator<Map>(m);
}
```

[Live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/EIKBSwrUoYfXDpMo)